# Autocomplete syntax for HTML or PHP in Notepad++. Not auto-close, autocompelete

Tags: php, html, autocomplete, notepad++

How can I get autocompletion of syntax for HTML or PHP in Notepad++?
Not auto-close, I am looking for autocompelete.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Go to:

**Settings -> Preferences** You will see a dialog box. There click the **Backup / Auto-completion** tab where you can set the auto complete option :)

Comment: and you can edit the auto-complete file at `.../Program Files/Notepad++/plugins/APIs/[insert language here].xml` just make sure that your XML is valid, and that the autocomplete is in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 11):

In Notepad++ v. 6.4.1 is this possibility in:**Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion** and there check *Enable auto-completion on each input*.

For auto-complete in code press `Ctrl + Enter`.

Answer (score 9):

Press `Ctrl + Space` to get a autocomplete hint.

Answer (score 7):

Go to:

Settings -> Preferences You will see a dialog box. There click the Auto-completion tab where you can set the auto complete option.See image below:
[image: Follow it]

If your code not detected automatically then you choose your coding language form **Language** menu

Answer (score 2):

**Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion** and there check Enable auto-completion on each input.
**Press Ctrl + Space** to get a autocomplete hint.
For auto-complete in code type the first letter then press **Ctrl + Enter.** all the inputs you have given will be listed.

Answer (score 1):

Its supported in notepad++ 5.0+ but not enabled by default.  You can enable it from settings -> preferences

Answer (score 0):

If you want extended auto-completion for PHP (not only for the code in the current window or standard classes), try out the "ACCPC" plugin: https://github.com/StanDog/npp-phpautocompletion

Comment: how can we use this plugin to auto complete codeigniter framework classes