# Notepad++ autocomplete for multiple files (whole project)

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

Is there a way to tell notepad++ to include multiple files (libraries) or possibly my whole project for autocomplete so I get suggestions for function names that are in another file?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049861/autocomplete-syntax-for-html-or-php-in-notepad-not-auto-close-autocompelete

Comment: @micb: That's not really a duplicate. He wants autocomplite works even if words are in another file.

Comment: That would indeed be a kick-ass feature!

Answer (score 2):

You might also have a look at [PythonScript plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) (also available in Plugin Manager) and write your own Python script.

The script could:

1. Parse all the open files and generate a list of all words
2. Create an auto-completion window based on the words found.

In the doc, I found the relevant functions

> **Editor.autoCShow(lenEntered, itemList)** Display a auto-completion list.
>   The lenEntered parameter indicates how many characters before the
>   caret should be used to provide context.
>
> See Scintilla documentation for SCI_AUTOCSHOW

I will have a look by myself when I get the time.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It seems not such baked solution exists now.

However, you can vote for the following idea in the Idea Torrent: [Idea #181: autocompletion across opened documents](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/181/)