# Typing minus followed by greater than (->) opens a popup in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Typing minus followed by greater than (->) opens a popup in Notepad++ with the following:

Please wait
Scanning root directory. This is done only after directory was changed and only once!
If you see this popup although root directory not changed, please consider to use a sub-folder (with less files).

[image of Notepad++ popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5dtv.jpg)

So... what's happening???

Comment: Where did you type that? Can't reproduce.

Comment: When editing a php file... In example: i type "this->" and happens!

Comment: It looks like you have [enabled auto-completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049861/autocomplete-syntax-for-html-or-php-in-notepad-not-auto-close-autocompelete). Notepad++ seems to be trying to load your project to do a suggestion while you type. I also have this option enabled, but I never have seen this behaviour, though. But then again, I don't usually do big changes in PHP using Notepad++.

Comment: I've been checking your answer (i really appreciate that), but... nothing there. I've been using Notepad++ for years never having a problem. In the past days i installed 2 plugins: "XBrackets Lite" and "TextFX Characters". I disabled them and then remove them but nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it and install again? I know that you want to know why, but sometimes in a hush it is good to solve the problem first.

Comment: Also, it would be good to know what is the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @JorgeCampos! Today i have uninstalled and installed Notepad++ latest version (6.8.8 at this moment) and restarted the system but this action doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer with a screen capture.

Answer (score 4):

I had have the some problem.

I uninstall the plugin "PHP Autocompletion" then the problem was solved.

It was the auto-completion function of this plugin.

Comment: Finally I know what is causing this!!!  Plugin description: "A popup window appears after typing the "->" or "::" behind a class or an instantiated object variable which displays all attributes and methods of it's class. As soon as the popup appears you can type in the name of the method or attribute you are looking for and the plugin will select it in the list automatically. Hitting [return] or double clicking the entry will insert the name of the property to your script. ..."  https://github.com/StanDog/npp-phpautocompletion